# What happens to lost threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, oop, thread-safety

Let's say I have a `list<Thread>`and then I `list.add(new MyThread())`. Assume `MyThread()` starts a `while` loop inside the thread. What happens to the thread when `list.RemoveOurThread()`? There is no longer a way to access the thread, but what happens to the `while` loop?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm trying to figure this out for a C# program

Comment: This is probably language-dependent. If you're asking about the behaviour in a specific programming language, please add a language tag to the question.

Comment: What @ScottLeis said, it all depends on the language.

Comment: I would like to know what happens for this situation in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most languages, the thread and while() loop will continue executing.  In Java, for example, nothing is garbage collected if it's referenced by an active thread; the fact that you can't access the thread from the outside does not prevent the thread from continuing to do useful work and performing I/O.  In C and C++, there's no garbage collector.